# Checkbox with selected items box

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox, checkboxlist

I need your help as shown below on the image that I would like to know the JavaScript codes for checkbox with selected items which should be shown below the selected item box. Thanks

[image: Checkbox]

Comment: document.getElementById("elementId").checked will give you true or false value depending upon the item/selector being checked or not. Is that what you want?

Comment: Show us the code so that we know where the problem is.

Comment: There is no problem. I've already completed the section but the problem was with selected items showing..  it's solved.. thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this HTML

```
<div class="taglist">
<label><input type="checkbox" value="2D Animation">2D Animation</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="3D Animation">3D Animation</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="Animatronics">Animatronics</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="Architectural">Architectural</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="Cartoon">Cartoon</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="Cell Animation">Cell   Animation</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="Character Animation">Character Animation</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="Cut & Paste">Cut & Paste</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="Doodle">Doodle</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="HDR">HDR</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="High Speed">High Speed</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="Illustration">Illustration</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="Live Action">Live Action</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="Macro">Macro</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="Motion Design">Motion Design</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="Motion Graphics">Motion Graphics</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="Moving Installation">Moving Installation</label>
</div>
```

use this html code and this script

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 function updateTextArea() {     
 var allVals = [];
 $('.taglist :checked').each(function(i) {

   allVals.push((i!=0?"\r\n":"")+ $(this).val());
 });
 $('#video0_tags').val(allVals).attr('rows',allVals.length) ;

 }
 $(function() {
  $('.taglist input').click(updateTextArea);
  updateTextArea();
 });
</script>
```

For reference this http://jsfiddle.net/7b5fk/1/

Comment: Hello, would you please tell me that how to place the selected items side by side? thanks